# How to get the private fields of class and its parent class(es) by reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, visibility

I have the class B and its parent class A, both in namespace Domain.

- Class A, has the private field a;
- Class B, has the private field b;

Then I have a Reflection Util in namespace Reflect.
If I use this line

```
instanceOfB.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic 
         | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
```

to to find all fields (a & b), I get only b. But when I make `a` protected or public I find them too.

What do I need to do to find the private fields of the base class too?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the [documented behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx):

> Specify BindingFlags.NonPublic to include non-public fields (that is, private, internal, and protected fields) in the search. Only protected and internal fields on base classes are returned; private fields on base classes are not returned.

If you need to get private fields, you'll need to ask the base type. (Use [`Type.BaseType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) to find the base type, and call `GetFields` on that.)

Comment: Please permit me to ask a bit more: When I go recursive throug the class hierarchy, how do I make sure, that I obtain every field (even public fields of the parent) only once?

Comment: @Ralph: You can use the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` to *avoid* getting fields inherited from base classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
instanceOfB.GetType().BaseType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
```

Answer (score -4):

```
 public class A
 {
     private int aa;
 }

 public class B
 {
     private int bb;
 }

System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = (new B()).GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic| BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Sir It works fine at my end , By following the above line of code. It shows the private variable.

Comment: The private variables of the *base* class? It shouldn't.

Comment: You haven't given any explanation at all - just code... which basically shows the same thing as the question, except you haven't made `B` derive from `A`.

Comment: I did not see any explanation. Anyway the "Problem" is that B must be a derived class of A. (And in your example it is not)